# Changing component variable in Angular test affects other tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In my test I'm importing a JSON file to set a mock value (which would usually be passed in to my component as an `@Input()`).

It was my impression that Angular tests would reset component variables before each test runs if `beforeEach` is used; therefore, changing the value of a component variable inside one test shouldn't affect other tests in the same testbed.

However, I'm finding that when a variable value is changed in a test it isn't being reset by the `beforeEach` before the next test runs.

**mock_board.json**

```
{
   "board": {
     "type": "Archived"
   }  
}
```

**component.spec.ts**

```js
import * as MockBoard from '../mock_board.json';
...

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture(MyComponent);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [
       ...
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.board = MockBoard['board'];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should display title if board type is `Progress`', () => {
    component.board.type = 'Progress';

    ... // expectation here
  });

  it('should change the UI if board data changes', () => {
    console.log(component.board.type); // expected 'Archived' but returns 'Progress'
  });

  ...
```

How can I ensure that component variables are always reset back to the original before each test runs?

---

**EDIT**

I managed to replicate the bug in StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-x7nkmv?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts).

In the second test, setting the value in this way:

```
component.board.type = 'Progress';
```

causes the next test to fail, whereas rewriting the whole object like this:

```
component.board = { id: 1, type: 'Progress' };
```

causes the next test to pass.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Can you show the complete test including the stuff before `beforeEach`?

Comment: @FabianKüng I updated the snippet to contain more code.

Comment: I replicated your component/test [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-8tfspc?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts), but everything works as expected. Is there some logic in your component that might modify the `board` variable? What is the content of the JSON you are using in your test?

Comment: You're right @FabianKüng, it _is_ running fine in your demo (as I expected mine to!). I posted the JSON contents above too.

Comment: What about the component code @timray? Everything looks good so far, all I can think of now is that the input parameter is somehow changed in the component / outside of the test.

Comment: Could you try `component.board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MockBoard['board'] ))` in the beforeEach. I think it is reusing the same reference for between tests. Making a new copy of the original before each test should resolve it.

Comment: @FabianKüng The component code is fairly long so I'll try to strip any extraneous code and post a StackBlitz link.

Comment: @Jelle you're right. Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` is the right approach. This creates a fresh object within the `beforeEach` block instead of directly assigning it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your StackBlitz (and many log statements!) it appears that when you change the value in `component.board` it was also changing the value in `data`. This makes sense as the assignment in the `beforeEach` method (`component.board = data;`) would just be assigning `component.board` the same pointer as `data`. Then changing one would change the other.

To get past this you should, as some of the comments mention, clone the `data` object rather than directly assigning it. You can do this using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MockBoard['board']))` as *Jelle* mentioned or use something like Lodash's `clone` method (`cloneDeep` for more complex objects).

[Here is an updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-ermkqh?file=app/dummy/dummy.component.spec.ts) that you can use to compare to your original code.

Comment: This, combined with @Jelle comment to my original question helped me solve the issue.
Directly assigning an object in a `beforeEach` was my mistake - I've used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` which is working as expected.